# Run a background Nodejs docker service on demand (via Gitlab CI ??)

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

I've only been in the Node.js Docker and CICD scene for a few months.

I'd like to describe a task I want to do and hope you can give me some keywords about the systems and services I'm getting on with. So it's more about a CICD pipeline... but I will certainly have to set up some systems first.

So let's try it:

I program in Node.js and use Docker for my containerization,
for project management I use Gitlab-CE from my own network,
I also get my docker images from my private registry.

I can build and run a microservice architecture, but:

I'm looking for a way to start, run and stop a Nodejs service in Docker only when needed... sounds simple, but I can't get in!

To be honest, I don't know yet who has to accept the request, how, for the Docker service, and then tell the service his task...

I've read about Jenkins, but Gitlab CI should be able to do that as well, allegedly.

Can anyone here tell me about their experiences?